# Compute $I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(t)}{e^{\pi t}-1}dt$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> I would like to compute $\displaystyle I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(t)}{e^{\pi t}-1}dt$

Let $D=(0,+\infty)$, I have $\frac{1}{e^{-\pi t}-1}=\frac{e^{-\pi t}}{1-e^{-\pi t}}$

So $$\frac{\arctan(t)}{e^{\pi t}-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\arctan(t)e^{-k \pi t}$$

Now, I can use integration term by term theorem, And finally I have,

$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}\arctan(t)e^{-k \pi t}dt
$$

By integration by parts I get,
$$
\int_0^{X}\arctan(t)e^{k \pi t}dt\rightarrow \frac{1}{k\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-k \pi t}}{1+t^2}dt
$$

Therefore,
$$
I=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-k \pi t}}{1+t^2}dt
$$

Now, I am stuck.

I would like to find a closed form,

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: $I=\dfrac{1-\ln2}2$

Comment: @Lucian Very instructive.

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis Yasser? I believe you can attack this using some methods from Residue theory. The shape I have in mind is a rectangle in the right upper half plane.

Comment: @BlueBuck Unfortunately I haven't knowledge on these subject.

Comment: @Lucian How did you get that result ?. Mathematica just return the integral without any evaluation. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin: By reaching down into the unfathomable depths of my astounding mathematical intellect, [how else](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian It was nice. Thanks.

Comment: I think you will also like [this solution](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=493626). See Doe John's generalization!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $ \displaystyle I(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan \frac{x}{z}}{e^{\pi x}-1} \ dx$.

Then

$$\begin{align}  I(z) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}-1} \frac{\sin (xt)}{t}e^{-zt} \ dt \ dx \tag{1} \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (tx)}{e^{\pi x}-1} \ dx \ dt \\&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin (tx) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi nx}\ dx \ dt \\ &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{t} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(tx) \ e^{-\pi n x} \ dx \ dt \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{t} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t}{t^{2} + \pi^{2}n^{2}} \\&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zt}}{t} \Big(\coth t -\frac{1}{t}\Big) \ dt \tag{2} \end{align}$$

Now differentiate inside of the integral with respect to $z$.

$$ I'(z) = - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt} \Big( \coth t - \frac{1}{t}\Big) \ dt $$

And then integrate by parts.

$$ \begin{align} I'(z) &= -\frac{1}{2} e^{-zt} \Big(\log(\sinh t) - \log t \Big) \Big|^{\infty}_{0} - \frac{z}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \Big( \log (\sinh t) - \log(t) \Big) \ dt \\ &=- \frac{z}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \Big( \log (\sinh t) - \log(t) \Big) \ dt \\ &= - \frac{z}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \Big(t - \log (2) + \log(1-e^{-2t}) - \log(t) \Big) \ dt  \\  &= -\frac{z}{2} \Big( \frac{1}{z^{2}} - \frac{\log(2)}{z} + \frac{\log(z) + \gamma}{z} \Big) + \frac{z}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zt} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2tn}}{n} \ dt \\ &= - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log z}{2} - \frac{\gamma}{2} +\frac{z}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(2n+z)t} \ dt  \\ &= - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log z}{2} - \frac{\gamma}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z/2}{n(n+z/2)} \\ &= - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log z}{2} - \frac{\gamma}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\psi\left( \frac{z}{2}+1 \right)  + \frac{\gamma}{2} \tag{3} \\ &= - \frac{1}{2z} + \frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log z}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \psi \Big( \frac{z}{2}+1 \Big) \end{align}$$

Then integrating back,

$$I(z) = - \frac{\log z}{2} + \frac{z \log 2}{2} - \frac{z \log z}{2} + \frac{z}{2} +  \log \Gamma \left( \frac{z}{2} +1 \right) + C$$

where using Stirling's formula the constant of integration is found to be $ \displaystyle -\frac{\log(\pi)}{2}$.

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x}{e^{\pi x}-1} \ dx &= I(1) \\ &= \frac{\log 2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \log \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2} \right)- \frac{\log \pi}{2} \\ &= \frac{\log 2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} +  \log \left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \right) -\frac{\log \pi}{2} \\ &=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\log 2}{2} \end{align}$$

$ $

$(1)$ [$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} \sin(x)}{x} dx$ Evaluate Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159836/int-0-infty-frace-x-sinxx-dx-evaluate-integral/159852#159852)

$(2)$ [Series expansion of $\coth x$ using the Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845506/series-expansion-of-coth-x-using-the-fourier-transform)

$(3)$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula

Comment: Surely an impressive answer, but I don't understand many steps here (yet). The first three..And I don't know what $\psi$ is ? If you can add some words with your steps, anyway I will try it tomorrow. I will let you know if I have some truble. Thanks!

Comment: This is a fairly difficult integral. And $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: I expressed I(z) as an iterated integral by using the fact that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin xt}{t} e^{-zt} \ dt = \arctan (\frac{x}{z})$ and then I switched the order of integration.

Comment: Nice answer. This is the second [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html)

Comment: @yzhao Thanks.  It's actually a variation of the formula since the exponent in the denominator has a $\pi$ and not a $2 \pi$.

Comment: Do you have a sketch for your first point ? Otherwise I have understood the rest of your proof, excellent!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{\arctan\pars{t} \over \expo{\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t}$

> \begin{align}
> I &=\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \expo{\pi t} - 1}
> \int_{0}^{t}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd t
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}
> \int_{x}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pi t} \over 1 - \expo{-\pi t}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-\pi x}} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> =-\,{1 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-\pi\bracks{x - \ic}}} \over x - \ic}\,\dd x
> \end{align}

Let's consider
$$
{\cal J}\pars{\mu} \equiv
-\,{1 \over \pi}\,\int_{0}^{\infty}\Im\pars{%
{\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-\mu\bracks{x - \ic}}}\over x - \ic}}\,\dd x\quad
\mbox{such that}\quad I = {\cal J}\pars{\pi}\tag{2}
$$

\begin{align}
{\cal J}'\pars{\mu}&=
{1 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\mu\bracks{x - \ic}} \over 1 + \expo{-\mu\bracks{x - \ic}}}\dd x
=\left.-\,{1 \over \pi\mu}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-\mu\bracks{x - \ic}}}
\right\vert_{x\ = 0}^{x\ \to\ \infty} 
\\[3mm]&={1 \over \pi\mu}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 + \expo{\ic \mu}}
={1 \over \pi\mu}\,\Im\ln\pars{2\expo{\ic\mu/2}\cos\pars{\mu \over 2}}
={1 \over 2\pi}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> Notice that $\ds{{\cal J}\pars{0} = -\,\half\,\ln\pars{2}}$
>   \begin{align}
> I&={\cal J}\pars{\pi}
> =-\,\half\,\ln\pars{2} + \bracks{{\cal J}\pars{\pi} - {\cal J}\pars{0}}
> =-\,\half\,\ln\pars{2}
> + \int_{0}^{\pi}\overbrace{{1 \over 2\pi}}^{\ds{\mbox{From}\ \pars{3}}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\ln\pars{2} + \half
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
I \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{\arctan\pars{t} \over \expo{\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t
=\half\bracks{1 - \ln\pars{2}}}
$$