# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{t}}{e^t-1}dt$?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Is it possible to compute $I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{t}}{e^t-1}dt$?

I encountered this problem while calculating sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1}$. This integral converges $I=\int_0^\varepsilon+\int_\varepsilon^\infty$, first integral is finite since $\sin{t}/(e^t-1)\tilde{} 1$ and the second is finite since $\sin{t}/(e^t-1)<e^{-t}$.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einf+sin%28x%29%2F%28exp%28x%29-1%29) gives $\frac{1}{2}(\pi\coth(\pi) - 1) \approx 1.07667$.  I'm not sure how you would go about showing that, though.

Comment: @DMcMor you get that by taking a complex contour approach on $\sum(n^2+1)^{-1}$ where coth is due to a rectangular contour (plenty of duplicates on mse), so I get op wants a different integral method

Comment: To op: it would be of benefit to you and others if you provide more context to your question such as the procedure to go $\sum_{n>0}1/(n^2+1)=\int_{t>0}\sin t/(e^t-1)\,dt$ (to prevent closure)

Comment: $$im\left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{it}}{e^t-1}\right)$$

Comment: A couple of solutions are here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235131/on-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-lambda-x-mathrmdxe2-pi-x-1/4235298#4235298

Comment: You could try setting $x=2\pi t$ and use the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula), but there are better methods.

Comment: @Svyatoslav I would like to see solution which is not from complex analysis, if possible.

Comment: Do you allow the use of Fourier series or Poisson summation formula ?

Comment: @Célestin Yes, I would like to see your solution by using Fourier series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First method.** *Using Poisson summation formula*
If a continuous integrable function $\varphi$ and its Fourier transform are rapidly going to zero at infinity (check its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) for more details) then
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \varphi(n) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat \varphi(n) $$ Since the *Fourier transform* tends to transform rapidly decreasing (to zero) functions to slowly decreasing (to zero) functions, and vice versa,  Poisson's formula is well suited to the calculations of certain series.

You can check that for $\varphi(x) = \pi e^{-2\pi |x|}$ we have $\hat \varphi(s) = \frac{1}{1+s^2}$. Poisson tells us that
$$  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \pi e^{-2\pi |n|}  $$ Use parity and geometric series to complete the computation.

**Second method.** *Using Parseval's identity for Fourier series*
Let $e_n(t) = e^{2\pi i nt}$ be the Fourier orthonormal system of $L^2[0,1]$ and recall  Parseval's identity :
$$ \forall f,g \in L^2[0,1] ~~,~~ \langle f,g\rangle  = \int_0^1 f(t)\overline{g(t)} \,\mathrm dt= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \langle f,e_n\rangle \overline{\langle g,e_n\rangle}  $$
Take $s \in \mathbf C\setminus \mathbf Z$ and let $z=\overline{s}$. Compute the Fourier coefficients of $f(t) = e^{2 \pi i st}$ and $g(t)=e^{2\pi i zt}$
$$ \langle f,e_n\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{2\pi i s}-1}{s-n} ~~\text{ and } ~~ \overline{\langle g,e_n\rangle} = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{-2\pi i s}-1}{s-n} $$ Using  Parseval's identity,  it comes, after some simplifications :
$$ \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi s)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{(s-n)^2} \tag{1} $$ Break the sum into three pieces, and write
$$\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi s)} = \frac{1}{s^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(s-n)^2} + \frac{1}{(s+n)^2} \tag{2} $$
Integrate $(2)$ both sides, then multiply by $-1$ to get the famous formula :
$$ \pi \cot(\pi s) =  \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2s}{s^2-n^2} $$ Replacing $s$ by $is$ leads to :
$$ \pi \coth (\pi s) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2s}{s^2 +n^2} $$ If you really want to avoid the use of any complex variable, replace $s$ by $is$ in $(1)$ or in $(2)$ then integrate in the « real » sense. Again, it is easy to recover the result given by WolframAlpha.

Also, using Fourier series and Dirichlet's theorem (for pointwise convergence) you may check other topics on MSE, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845506/series-expansion-of-coth-x-using-the-fourier-transform). :)

**ADDENDUM.** We can reach our goal a bit faster. Apply Parseval's identity to $f(t)=  e^{2\pi ist}$ and $g(t) = \overline{f(t)}$ :
$$ \int_0^1 f(t)^2 \mathrm dt = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \langle f,e_n\rangle \langle f,e_{-n}\rangle  $$ Substitute things...
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{e^{4 \pi i s}-1}{2s} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \bigg(\frac{e^{2\pi is} - 1}{2\pi i} \bigg)^2 \frac{1}{s^2-n^2} $$ Simplify some terms...
$$ 2\pi \cot(\pi s) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2s}{s^2-n^2} $$ Finally, by symmetry in $n\neq 0$
$$ \pi \cot(\pi s) = \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2s}{s^2-n^2} $$

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{e^t-1}d 
t=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}\sin t}{1-e^{-t}}d 
t= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin t~ e^{-(n+1)x}dt$$
Use $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at} \sin t~dt=\frac{1}{1+a^2}$
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^2}$$
See [Approximate $\coth(x)$ around $x = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109021/approximate-cothx-around-x-0)
for the proof of
$$\coth z-1/z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2z}{\pi^2 n^2+ z^2}$$
Taking $z=\pi$, we prove that $$I=\frac{\pi}{2} \coth \pi-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Exactly what I would have done. (+1)