# I can't get a result for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k^2+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Using partial fractions:
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{i}{2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+i} - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k-i} \right) $$
Expanding and rationalising end up with:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{i}{2}\left( -i +  \frac{1-i}{1^2+1} + \cdots +  \frac{n-i} {n^2+1} +\left( -i  \frac{1+i}{1^+1} -\cdots-  \frac{n+i}{n^2+1}  \right)\right) $$
Simplifying I end up with an expanded version of what I started with:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 +\frac{1}{1^2+1} + \frac{1}{2^2+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^2+1}\right) $$
How can I solve this problem? I feel like I am just going in circles.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2} (1+\pi  \coth (\pi ))$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845506/series-expansion-of-coth-x-using-the-fourier-transform

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2