# Sum of $\sum_0^\infty \frac1{n^4+a^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

How to find the following series as pretty closed form by $a$?
$$S=\sum_0^\infty \frac1{n^4+a^4}$$
I first considered applying Herglotz trick, simply because the expressions are similar. So I changed it like this...
$$2S-a^{-4}=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{n^4+a^4}$$
However, the attempt failed to find such an appropriate function like $\pi\cot\pi z$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work/581206#581206).

Next I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2/208407#208407) and used Fourier transform in a similar way, and the result was a nightmare!

[image]

How on earth can I calculate the value of this series?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha we have that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4+a^4}=-\frac{\pi\left(\sin(\sqrt{2}\pi a)+\sinh(\sqrt{2}\pi a)\right)}{\sqrt{2}a^3\left(\cos(\sqrt{2}\pi a)-\cosh(\sqrt{2}\pi a)\right)}$, so I'm suspecting there's no short solution

Comment: I must have misjudged that that would be simpler than I thought. Thanks for letting me know, @Lorago . Nevertheless, I want to know how that is induced.

Comment: several solutions are here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384780/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n4a4?noredirect=1 IMHO, the most regular way is the integration in the complex plane with the functions $\pi\cot\pi z$ or $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$- what allows to get closed forms for different sums of types $\frac{1}{n^{2k}+a}, \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k}+a}$, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We start with partial fractions,
$$\frac{1}{n^4+a^4} = \frac{i}{2a^2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2 + i a^2} - \frac{1}{n^2 - i a^2}\right) \tag 1$$
And then note that ([Series expansion of $\coth x$ using the Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845506/series-expansion-of-coth-x-using-the-fourier-transform))
$$\coth x = \frac{1}{x} + 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+\pi^2n^2}$$
which we rearrange to give:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^2+n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{2x}\left(\coth x - \frac{1}{x} \right) $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)^2+n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{x^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{2x}\left(\coth x - \frac{1}{x} \right) =\frac{\pi^2}{2x^2}\left(x \coth x + 1 \right) \tag 2$$
and so
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4+a^4} = \frac{i}{2a^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n^2 + i a^2} - \frac{1}{n^2 - i a^2}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{i}{2a^2}\frac{\pi^2}{2ia^2\pi^2}\left(\sqrt{i}a \pi \coth \sqrt{i}a - \sqrt{-i}a \pi \coth \sqrt{-i}a\right) $$
$$ = \frac{\pi}{4a^3}\left(e^{i\pi/4}  \coth \sqrt{i}a - e^{3i\pi/4} \coth \sqrt{-i}a\right) $$
which I'm sure can be further simplified but I will leave there for now.

Comment: Holy god! I've never thought of that before!!!! Thanks! It seems to have been resolved perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my short answer but the result is

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{a^4+n^4}=\frac{1}{2 a^4}+\frac{\pi  \left(\sin \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)+\sinh \left(\sqrt{2}
   \pi  a\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2} a^3 \left(\cosh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)-\cos
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)\right)}
$

No complex numbers are needed!
For the calculation the path of [Blitzer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/429808/blitzer) is appropriate but the calculations are seemingly wrong to me. My result has both sites are real as required.
My solution can be verified on [wolframcloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com) are no extra cost. Simply type in the infinite sum as given. Hope that helps so far.
Here is a reference of the formula under consideration: [Coth](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/06/05/) with constraints. Here some formula how to deal with the imaginary unit: [Coth](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/introductions/Coth/01/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you write
$$n^4+a^4=(n-\alpha)(n-\beta)(n-\gamma)(n-\delta)$$
$$\alpha=-\frac{(1+i) a}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad \beta=\frac{(1+i) a}{\sqrt{2}}\qquad \gamma=-\frac{(1-i) a}{\sqrt{2}} \qquad \delta=\frac{(1-i) a}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Using partial fraction
$$\frac 1{n^4+a^4}=\frac{1}{(\alpha-\beta) (\alpha-\gamma) (\alpha-\delta) (x-\alpha)}+\frac{1}{(\beta-\alpha) (\beta-\gamma) (\beta-\delta) (x-\beta)}+$$ $$\frac{1}{(\gamma-\alpha) (\gamma-\beta) (\gamma-\delta) (x-\gamma)}+\frac{1}{(\delta-\alpha) (\delta-\beta) (\delta-\gamma) (x-\delta)}$$

Now,consider the partial sum
$$S_p(\epsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac 1{n-\epsilon}=\psi (p+1-\epsilon )-\psi (-\epsilon )$$  Compute all sums and use the asymptotics of the digamma function for large $p$ to obtain for large $p$
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac 1{n^4+a^4}=\frac{1}{2 a^4}+\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2} a^3} \frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)+\sin \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)}{\cosh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)-\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)}-\frac{1}{3 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$

$$\color{red}{S_\infty=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{n^4+a^4}=\frac{1}{2 a^4}+\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2} a^3} \frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)+\sin \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)}{\cosh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)-\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  a\right)}}$$