# Is the double integral exists for $ f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y} \sin x}{x} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Define the function: $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R} $,

$$ f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-y} \sin x}{x} $$
where $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is the set of real numbers without zero.

$1.$ Evaluate "if exist" the double integral for the function defined over the set $S = (0, n) \times (0, \infty) $.

$2.$ Then compare it with the double integral of the function, defined on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, $h(x,y) = e^{-xy} \sin x$

I am suffering from this question and really I don't know how to deal with it. Any help please?

The integral of a similar function with one variable was discussed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159836/int-0-infty-frace-x-sinxx-dx-evaluate-integral) but the solution doesn't help in my case.

Comment: You take the double integral, and note that you can split it up into a product of two integrals, both of which work.

Comment: Fubini's theorem

Comment: In the second, you can just integrate $y$ out of there, treating $x$ as a constant, and then working with the rest

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb R^*$?

Comment: @Math1000 the set of real numbers without zero